# How can I repair a leaking shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower

We have a leaking shower. We have replaced the seat and stem on the  water but it still leaks. Also the diverter does not shut off all the water.

Comment: Did you try replacing the o-rings, if not the whole cartridge?

Comment: A bit more detail (brand and model, etc.) might help for a repair. Pictures might help (including of the valve parts when they are out.) Replacement is always an option, if a bit messy in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

To oversimplify things, a shower control has two parts: the fixed part attached to the pipes in the wall, and everything else (which is usually the cartridge and possibly some O-rings if they are separate).

If you've replaced "everything else", then the problem is the fixed part in the wall.